# webview and local html

Tags: android

I've putted a webview and with this code I use it with local html. Now, I'd like add images to this html but I don't know where put that images. Any advice?

```
String html = "<html><body>Hello, World!</body></html>";
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";

WebView myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Comment: Android -->> Not meant to do this. The problem lies in picking up the images. If the images lie on a server the browser can pick them up. But if their on your phone, the `src` attribute can't be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a html page in the in `assets/` folder.
How to add images to a html file is decribed [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

Then load that page in the WebView:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the image in the html file then you need to make the changes as below:

> ```
> String html ="<html><body>Hello, World!" +
>             "<img src=\"C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/pulpit.jpg\" alt=\"Pulpit rock\" width=\"304\" height=\"228\" /></body></html>";
> ```

Thanks.

Comment: Huh? Is a local path? (c:/users[...])

Comment: Path you can define on your own. Its just to give you idea.